# Como adicionar barra de rolagem em JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, layout

Eu gostaria de adicionar uma barra de rolagem em um JPanel que usa Absolute Layout.

```
    package Default;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

    import java.awt.Dimension;

    import javax.swing.JButton;
    import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

    public class teste extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        teste frame = new teste();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static int qtButton = 0 ;

    public teste() 
    {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 500, 500);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        JScrollPane panel = new JScrollPane();
        panel.setBounds(10, 11, 464, 439);
        contentPane.add(panel);

        for(int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
        {
            gerarButton(panel);
        }   

    }
    public static void gerarButton(JScrollPane panel)
    {
        JButton NewButton = new JButton("New button");
        NewButton.setBounds(10, 11 + (34 * qtButton), 444, 23);
        panel.add(NewButton);

        qtButton ++;

        panel.repaint();
    }
}
```

E aqui do jeito que fica

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como eu poderia fazer isso ??

Obs: os botões dentro são "infinitos"

Comment: Use JScrollPane, ao inves de JPanel.

Comment: @DiegoF Eu usei e mesmo assim não funcionou

Comment: Sete um tamanho para o `JScrollPane`, usando `setPreferredSize`.

Comment: @DiegoF Eu gostaria de um exemplo no código que eu coloquei na pergunta, poderia fazer isso ??

Answer (score 2):

> **Evite usar layout absoluto, a não ser que seja de extrema necessidade e que saiba as consequências disso**, pois layout absoluto dificulta manutenção da tela e faz com que sua aplicação fique com aparência diferente dependendo do monitor e resolução que estiver sendo executada.
>
> Existem vários [**gerenciadores de layouts**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) para que você não tenha que se preocupar com posicionamento ou organização manual de componentes. Sem contar que o uso de layouts faz com que seu código fique mais fácil de dar manutenção do que ficar inserindo um monte de `setbounds`, e caso precise alterar a posição de algum componente, vai ter que reposicionar todos manualmente.

No código apresentado, o problema é resolvido de uma maneira alternativa e  bastante simples: utilizando [`GridLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/GridLayout.html). Este layout organiza os componentes de um container na forma de uma grade, onde você define quantas linhas e colunas ele deve possuir. No seu caso, o número de linhas é indefinido, então basta passar 0 no primeiro parâmetro do construtor([que representa o numero de linhas](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/GridLayout.html#GridLayout-int-int-)) e deixar por conta do layout.

E para que o scroll funcione corretamente, você precisa criar um painel com o layout informado, e adicionar este painel ao `JScrollPane`, e não adicionar os botoes diretamente, pois assim o scrollpane não saberá em qual componente ele vai se basear no tamanho para exibir o scroll.

Fiz algumas alterações no seu código, removendo o layout absoluto, uma vez que misturar layouts relativo e absoluto não irá trazer o resultado esperado:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

public class GridLayoutButtonsTest extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private int qtButton = 0; 
    
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        GridLayoutButtonsTest frame = new GridLayoutButtonsTest();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    public GridLayoutButtonsTest() 
    {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane();
        scroll.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(464, 439));

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1, 10, 10));
        
        for(int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
        {
            panel.add(gerarButton());
        }
        scroll.setViewportView(panel);
        contentPane.add(scroll);
        
        pack();
    }
    
    public JButton gerarButton() {
        
        qtButton++;
        JButton NewButton = new JButton(String.valueOf(qtButton));
        return NewButton;
    }
}
```

Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mais informações de uso a respeito deste layout podem ser encontradas no [Guia oficial da oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html).